# Error Handling in PHP and redirecting to Error Page

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I would like to log an error if occured on a php webpage and redirect the user to a custom error page. How can this be acheived. I am currently using the

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

for logging all errors.

What is the best practice to show the error page after handling the error in php.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can use PHP [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). They're not too popular (currently, anyway) but they work just swell.

Just `throw new MyException("Error text")` and catch it during your main page's execution, where you can print your pretty error page.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect should never be used.
Just show error page in place. Just add these lines right in your error handler

```
header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable");
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/503.html");
exit;
```

of course it would work only if your application is properly planned using templates, doing no output before all logic is done

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom class for this:

```php
/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class CommonException extends Exception {
    private $logFile = "../log/commonEx.log";
    private $log = Array();
    public $code = "";

    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) {                             
        $exLog['msg'] = $message;
        $exLog['code'] = $code;
        $this->code = $code;

        $exLog['file'] = $this->getFile();
        $exLog['line'] = $this->getLine();

        $this->log = $exLog;
        $this->_writeToLog($exLog);
        sfLoader::loadHelpers('I18N');
    }

    public function display() {
        return $this->log;
    }

    private function _writeToLog($exLog) {
        error_log(implode("|", $exLog) . "\r\n", 3, $this->logFile);
    }
}
```

In your `try .. catch` block:

```php
try {
    // ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errMsg = new CommonException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    // redirect to anywhere you want
}
```

Comment: In this case I will have to be putting the redirect code in all my catch blocks, right?

Comment: Yes or u can create ur custome function in this class to ridirect